# Getting "Filter chain halted as :validate_account_update_params rendered or redirected" when trying to update user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am using ng-token-auth and devise_token_auth for authentication. When I am trying to update user using

```
$auth.updateAccount
```

it's showing me

```
Unpermitted parameters: credentials, registration
Filter chain halted as :validate_account_update_params rendered or redirected
```

I have included the following in application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
private
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name << :credentials
end
```

Also, credentials field is serialized as an Array in the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :credentials, Array
end
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: No, I changed the architecture of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and finally found a solution.  For me, the problem was that the parent filter `:validate_account_update_params` was being called before the child `:configure_permitted_parameters`.  This is apparently new behavior as of at least Rails 4.2 (and possibly before).  Adding this in the child fixed it:

`prepend_before_action :configure_permitted_params`